# Which is more correct: <h1><a>..</a></h1> OR <a><h1>..</h1></a> from SEO point of view?

Tags: seo, html5

I read the [same question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7023512/1090562), but it was only addressing HTML complaint point of view. Moreover with HTML5 it does not make so much difference. I assume (without anything to back up my assumption), that the first approach is might be better from SEO point of view.

So is there any difference?

Comment: What is ceo? I think you are saying about SEO..

Comment: @SathiyaKumar thanks for edit. You are correct :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it doesn't matter for SEO. It's HTML5, it is (almost) a standard, they simply "aren't allowed" to give you bad credit.

I think this is more of a UX question. A header is a block level element and will be 100% width. An anchor is inline and will only wrap the text.

With that knowledge, you have two options:

- Wrap the `<h1>` around the `<a>` -> only the text is clickable
- Wrap the `<a>` around the `<h1>` -> the whole line is now clickable

In the end you'll get the most points if users stay on your site, better UX helps with that.