# Is it SEO safe to embed the H2 or H3 tag in a hyperlink element?

Tags: seo, html, hyperlink, heading

I'm making a new layout for our website, and I want to make a list using the unordered list tag (`ul`) to show our offers. But because of our design I would like to use the `h3` tag into an `a` element.

How would my idea impact SEO?

Here's an example in code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<a><h3>Header</h3><p>Text</p></a>
```

I believe the following HTML (which contains my idea) is valid, but how would it affect SEO?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title>
    <body>
        <a>
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <p>Text</p>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not valid HTML

Comment: Do you have a h1 tag as well?

Comment: @illinoistimYes I have one h1

Comment: @John Conde according to this validator https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea (just put my HTML)  it is valid

Comment: What does such an `a` element contain exactly? The heading for the offer name and a short description? Or more/longer content? Would each offer be in a `li` element which contains nothing else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules are simple regarding to this:

**You are not allowed to wrap an *inline* element around a *block* element.

The exception: If you use HTML5, you may wrap in anchor around a block element.**

From a **SEO perspective** it doesn't have influence, it's valid html so they wont discredit for that.

It **doesn't help** either. You're ramming a whole paragraph into an anchor, making the value of each word in it very very small, and you also stuff it with words your don't care about (*"This is an example" » only keyword is 'example', yet the whole sentence is the anchor*).

From **User Interface** point of view, it *can* (depends on the implementation) be very odd, the whole paragraph is a link? "*Huh, I just clicked plain text and now I've changed page?!*".

- [David Walsh has a small article with almost the exact same example](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links)
- [Which is more correct: <h1><a>..</a></h1> OR <a><h1>..</h1></a> from SEO point of view?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/which-is-more-correct-h1a-a-h1-or-ah1-h1-a-from-seo-point-o/61252#61252)
- [Difference between a block and an inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Comment: Good answer. I've done things like this when linking title & excerpt cards to blog posts. But, yeah, probably not a wise SEO strategy if that's the only reason you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping an anchor around blocks is acceptable in HTML5, not in previous versions like [HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)/XHTML.

In HTML5 we have:

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables,
>   and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive
>   content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

-> https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

e.g.:

```
<aside class="advertising">
 <h1>Advertising</h1>
 <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=1929&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
   <h1>Mellblomatic 9000!</h1>
   <p>Turn all your widgets into mellbloms!</p>
   <p>Only $9.99 plus shipping and handling.</p>
  </section>
 </a>
 <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=375&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
   <h1>The Mellblom Browser</h1>
   <p>Web browsing at the speed of light.</p>
   <p>No other browser goes faster!</p>
  </section>
 </a>
</aside>
```

So yes, it is valid HTML and safe to use it if you use HTML5, it won't be safe if you want to make it compatible with other versions of HTML.

*Update*
**Is this SEO valid?**

This is just like asking if using an HTML tag is valid for SEO, they are not valid per se, but what makes them SEO valid is the context where they are used.

If it was not valid HTML then it won't be appropriate for SEO, but being valid HTML doesn't makes it SEO valid, it will depend how you use it to structure your content.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do now it is valid, but I want to know more about SEO impact is it good practise to put `<h*>` in `<a>` or rather vice versa

Comment: @bumerang I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good SEO comes from good page content. Good SEO also comes from correct markup. Naturally as HTML5 is a total mess of non-clear markup rules I would stick to Xhtml versions if you do not need canvas commands. Anyhow I would not play tricks. I would get great page content and proper markup and make lots of pages and get good results. Google feels the love you put into your work.